# Syntax Error with `<` in Coq Notations

Tags: parsing, syntax, operators, coq, notation

The following code:

```
Reserved Notation "g || t |- x < y" (at level 10).

Inductive SubtypeOf :
  GammaEnv -> ThetaEnv -> UnsafeType -> UnsafeType -> Set :=
| SubRefl :
    forall (gamma : GammaEnv) (theta : ThetaEnv) (u : UnsafeType) , gamma || theta |- u < u
where "g || t |- x < y" := (SubtypeOf g t x y).
```

gives the following error:

```
Syntax error: '<' expected after [constr:operconstr level 200] (in [constr:operconstr])
```

I get a similar error if I use `<:` in place of `<`.

But this code works fine:

```
Reserved Notation "g || t |- x << y" (at level 10).

Inductive SubtypeOf :
  GammaEnv -> ThetaEnv -> UnsafeType -> UnsafeType -> Set :=
| SubRefl :
    forall (gamma : GammaEnv) (theta : ThetaEnv) (u : UnsafeType) , gamma || theta |- u << u
where "g || t |- x << y" := (SubtypeOf g t x y).
```

Why? Is there a precedence setting that can be changed to allow `<` or `<:` in notation? Is there built-in syntax that I'm colliding with, and need to watch for when defining notations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Coq uses an LL1 parser to process notations. It also can output the grammar. So, let's check what we are getting with the following

```
Reserved Notation "g || t |- x < y" (at level 10).
```

`Print Grammar constr.` outputs:

```
...
| "10" LEFTA
  [ SELF;
    "||";
    constr:operconstr LEVEL "200";        (* subexpression t *)
    "|-";
    constr:operconstr LEVEL "200";        (* subexpression x *)
    "<";
    NEXT
...
```

Here,

- `10` is our precedence level;
- `LEFTA` means left associativity;
- `200` is the default precedence level for inner subexpressions.

Taking into account the fact that a lower level binds more tightly than a higher level and the fact that the level of `<` is 70 (see [`Coq.Init.Notations`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Notations.html)), we can deduce that Coq is trying to parse the `x < y` part as a subexpression for `x`, consuming the `<` token, hence the error message.

To remedy the situation we can explicitly disallow parsing the third parameter as the less-than expression by assigning `x` higher precedence, i.e. a lower level.

```
Reserved Notation "g || t |- x < y" (at level 10, x at level 69).

Print Grammar constr.

| "10" LEFTA
  [ SELF;
    "||";
    constr:operconstr LEVEL "200";        (* subexpression t *)
    "|-";
    constr:operconstr LEVEL "69";         (* subexpression x *)
    "<";
    NEXT
```