# Overloading operators in Coq notations

Tags: operator-overloading, coq

I'd like to create notations for several kinds of judgements, for example for a typing and subtyping relation:

```
Reserved Notation "Г '⊢' t '∈' T" (at level 40).
Reserved Notation "Г '⊢' T '<:' U" (at level 40).

Inductive typing_relation : context -> term -> type -> Prop := ...
where "Γ '⊢' t '∈' T" := (typing_relation Γ t T).

Inductive subtyping_relation : context -> type -> type -> Prop := ...
where "Г '⊢' T '<:' U" := (subtyping_relation Γ T U).
```

As I understand, Coq will not allow this because the `⊢` operator is overloaded in those definitions.

How could I make Coq infer the definition of an overloaded operator (in this case, `⊢`) based on the types of its arguments (e.g. `term` vs `type`) (and/or based on the other operators that are part of the notation, e.g. `∈` vs `<:`)?

(Note that using different symbols would not be an option, because my Coq program defines several typing and subtyping relations.)

EDIT: Here is a minimal example:

```
Inductive type : Type :=
  | TBool : type.

Inductive term : Type :=
  | tvar : nat -> term.

Definition context := nat -> (option type).

Reserved Notation "G '⊢' t '∈' T" (at level 40).

Inductive typing_relation : context -> term -> type -> Prop :=
 | T_Var : forall G x T,
      G x = Some T ->
      G ⊢ tvar x ∈ T
 where "G '⊢' t '∈' T" := (typing_relation G t T).

Reserved Notation "G '⊢' T '<:' U" (at level 40).

Inductive subtype_relation : context -> type -> type -> Prop :=
  | S_Refl : forall G T,
      G ⊢ T <: T
  where "G '⊢' T '<:' U" := (subtype_relation G T U).
```

This results in the error:

```
Syntax error: '<:' or '∈' expected after [constr:operconstr level 200] (in [constr:operconstr]).
```

Comment: What error message do you get? Also, a [mcve] would be nice.

Comment: Just added an example!

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239138/syntax-error-with-in-coq-notations) is a related question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you cannot use `<:` like that, because `<:` is already defined as Coq's [typecast notation](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual003.html#typecast). It acts as if it was defined like so

```
Reserved Notation "t <: T" (at level 100, right associativity).
```

The situation is analogous to the one described in The Coq Reference Manual ([§12.1.3](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual014.html#sec536)):

> In the last case though, there is a conflict with the notation for type casts. This last notation, as shown by the command `Print Grammar constr.` is at level 100. To avoid `x : A` being parsed as a type cast, it is necessary to put `x` at a level below 100, typically 99.

Here is a possible solution for your situation:

```
Reserved Notation "G '⊢' t '∈' T" (at level 40, t at level 99).
Reserved Notation "G '⊢' T '<:' U" (at level 40, T at level 99).
```

Comment: This change made the above code compile. However, I am not able to actually use the notation. The following code:
`Definition t1 G t T := G ⊢ t ∈ T.` results in the error `Syntax error: '<:' expected after [constr:operconstr level 99] (in [constr:operconstr]).`

Comment: Coq is using an LL1 parser, so you need to modify all the notations that start with the same token. I updated the answer.