# Using a 3 symbols notation [constr:operconstr] expected after [constr:operconstr]

Tags: coq, notation

Say I have a relation and its reflexive and transitive closure (with `n` counting the number of "transitive steps":

```
Variable A: Type.

Inductive Relation: A -> A -> Prop :=
| rel: forall (a b: A), Relation a b.

Notation "a --> b" := (Relation a b) (at level 50).

Inductive Refl_Trans_Rel: A -> A -> nat -> Prop :=
| zero_step: forall a b, a --> b -> Refl_Trans_Rel a b 0
| n_steps: forall a b c n, a --> b /\ Refl_Trans_Rel b c n
    -> Refl_Trans_Rel a c (S n).
```

Now, I want to have a notation similiar as `a --> b`:

```
Notation "a -->^ n b" :=
  (Refl_Trans_Rel a b n) (at level 50, n at next level, b at next level).
```

For printing, there is no problem: `Check forall a b n, Refl_Trans_Rel a b n.` indeed prints:

```
forall (a b : A) (n : nat), a -->^ n b
 : Prop
```

However, when I want to use the notation myself, there is a problem:

```
Check forall a b n, a -->^ n b.
```

fail with:

```
Syntax error: [constr:operconstr] expected after [constr:operconstr]
  (in [constr:operconstr]).
```

Any idea of why it fails ?

---

P.S.: feel free to edit the title with something more precise, since I have no idea of the cause, I have no idea for a better title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Coq is trying to parse the `n b` part in `a -->^ n b` as a function application. One way of overcoming this difficulty would be to put `n` at a lower level, like so:

```
Notation "a -->^ n b" := (Refl_Trans_Rel a b n) (at level 50, n at level 9).
Check forall (a b : A) (n : nat), a -->^ n b.
```

Another option is to put a separator between `b` and `n`:

```
Notation "a --> b # n" := (Refl_Trans_Rel a b n) (at level 50).
Check forall (a b : A) (n : nat), a --> b # n.
```

You can find out more about notations and parsing levels [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42243936/2747511).

Comment: Your first option works perfectly and is exactly what I tried to achieve. I also tried adding a separator between `b` and `n` prior to ask the question as you suggest, but the I have a problem when I try to use `-->` without the `#`, e.g.: `Check forall a b, a --> b.` fails with `Syntax error: "#" expected after [constr:operconstr level 200] (in [constr:operconstr]).` That being said, I should re-read section 12.1 of the manual to really get the level related stuff.

Comment: (1) If you have `Notation "a --> b" := (Relation a b) (at level 50).` and `Notation "a --> b # n" :=
  (Refl_Trans_Rel a b n) (at level 50, b at next level).` then it should work.   (2) There has been a recent discussion of notations on Coq Club: [here](https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/arc/coq-club/2017-12/msg00010.html). It might help.

Comment: Sorry for commenting on a very old answer, but why level 9 specifically? I can't see anything special in Print Grammar constr at that level.

Comment: @shardulc I believe function application is at level 10. `Print Grammar constr` outputs this for me:  `"10" LEFTA
  [ SELF; LIST1 constr:appl_arg`. It seems to me `appl_arg` is what we are looking for here.